# How to correctly stop busybox shell process and child process?

Tags: kill, busybox

#### The actual server process is spawned by a shell script

I am trying to write an init script for djb [daemontools](https://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html) within [Entware](https://github.com/Entware-ng/Entware-ng) on a router running busybox 1.24 (ash shell). The daemontools way to start itself, is using the [svscanboot](https://cr.yp.to/daemontools/svscanboot.html) shell script. Note that I have removed [readproctitle](https://cr.yp.to/daemontools/readproctitle.html) from svscanboot.

```
PATH=/opt/sbin:/opt/bin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin
exec </dev/null
exec >/dev/null
exec 2>/dev/null
/opt/bin/svc -dx /opt/service/* /opt/service/*/log
env - PATH=$PATH svscan /opt/service 2>&1
```

The parent shell script process spawns a (descendant) `svscan` child process, which is the actual running server process.

#### The TERM signal is received by the shell process

Running `svscanboot &` (in background) and killing the parent process results in the child process running:

```
# ps l | grep svscan
S     0  1526     1  1560   404 0:0   22:57 00:00:00 {svscanboot} /bin/sh /opt/bin/svscanboot
S     0  1528  1526   976   252 0:0   22:57 00:00:00 svscan /opt/service
# killall svscanboot
```

#### But svscan will continue to run

```
# ps l | grep svscan
S     0  1528     1   976   252 0:0   22:57 00:00:00 svscan /opt/service
```

Executing `svscanboot` (in foreground) and killing the parent process also results in the child process still running:

```
# ps l | grep svscan
S     0   676   671  1560   400 pts1  23:41 00:00:00 {svscanboot} /bin/sh /opt/bin/svscanboot
S     0   678   676   976   252 pts1  23:41 00:00:00 svscan /opt/service
# killall svscanboot
# ps l | grep svscan
S     0   678     1   976   252 pts1  23:41 00:00:00 svscan /opt/service
```

Busybox is quite limited, `killall` only has flags `-l` and `-q` and `ps` only has `w`ide, `l`ong and show `T`hreads.

And when quitting the foreground version with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> both parent and child processes are terminated.

How to stop both the parent and the child process in this case, preferably using `killall` and eventually by modifying `svscanboot`?

Comment: Running `svscan*` processes forever is normal behaviour. Do you have any special reason to stop them?

Comment: @IporSircer Most init scripts have actions like: start, stop, restart, kill, etcetera. For the sake of having an init script that works the way most users do expect it to, I do want to stop deamontools (`svscan*`).

Comment: `svscan` has a similar job like `systemd`, so it is the recommended way to leave it run forever. If you don't wanna use its features, then remove it completely and start your services directly from initscripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### To exec

After I read the question and answer of [Meaning of "exec env COMMAND "](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/265405/meaning-of-exec-env-command) a possible solution could be to prefix the `env …` with an `exec`. That will prevent the spawning of a child process. However `ps` outputs `{svscanboot} /bin/sh /opt/bin/svscanboot`. That name will change to `svscan /opt/service` after the `exec`.

#### Or to trap signals

The other way to handle this is via a trap that propagates the signals to the child process. Like [Forward SIGTERM to child in Bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146756/forward-sigterm-to-child-in-bash) or the in more detail explained http://veithen.github.io/2014/11/16/sigterm-propagation.html
The issue with this solution route is that SIGKILL a.k.a. signal number `-9` can not be trapped.

#### <strike>Exec with a name change workaround</strike>

<strike>For not being able to trap the KILL signal, I will choose for the `exec` route:</strike>

```
…
exec env - PATH=$PATH svscan /opt/service 2>&1
```

<strike>This does still make things complicated to stop/kill/reconfigure "svscanboot" within the Entware init system because of the changed name. That exec process name change will need a workaround.</strike>

#### Mimic svscanboot

The entware-daemontools-init-script can be changed to mimic `svscanboot`, like:

```
ENABLED=yes
#PRECMD="exec </dev/null;exec >/dev/null;exec 2>/dev/null;/opt/bin/svc -dx /opt/service/* /opt/service/*/log"
PROCS="svscan"
ARGS="/opt/service 2>&1"
PATH=/opt/sbin:/opt/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
PREARGS="env - PATH=$PATH"
DESC="daemontools"
```

The commented PRECMD makes that `svscan` will not be started.